# PHP mail function is not working for Webform

Tags: php

Below is the Webform PHP code I used for e-mail function. After I click the SUBMIT button in the form, I am successfully getting redirected to the thankyou.html page but I don't get any e-mail to my e-mail account. Kind help is deeply appreciated.

```
PHP Code:
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['name']."\n"
.'E-mail: '.$_POST['email']."\n"
.'Phone: '.$_POST['phone']."\n"
.'Address: '.$_POST['addr']."\n"
.'City: '.$_POST['city']."\n"
.'State: '.$_POST['state']."\n"
.'Enquiry: '.$_POST['msg'];
mail('myemail@email.com', 'Subject Line', $emailbody);
header('location: thankyou.html');
} else {
header('location: index.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: read the documentation first.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Lots of stuff that could have gone wrong here. Are you testing this on a web server which has a mail server installed along with an MTA? Did you test the result of the `mail` function (true on successful sending, false on errors)?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a good quality mailer class such as phpMailer or Swiftmailer rather than php's built-in `mail()` function. There are a many things that can go wrong; using one of these will avoid a lot of them (or give you meaningful error messages if they happen).

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the "From" field in the $additional_headers argument. Try

```
$headers = 'From: myemail@email.com';
mail('myemail@email.com', 'Subject Line', $emailbody, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with your host.

I think due to the email spams that @email.com got from your host it may be now in the blacklist.

**This means you have to contact your host about this problem and tell them to talk with @email.com to remove your host from the blacklist.**

---

I had this problem a while ago on [000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com/) and they told me i can't send emails to an yahoo.com account because yahoo.com added the [000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com/) on the blacklist because users spammed the Yahoo servers.

Comment: Hi boyd, My e-mail is not blacklisted as I have tried with different e-mails but in vain.

Comment: Not your email is blacklisted . Your host's email is blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your server, or one along the route, is refusing to deliver the mail because it has no `From:` address. You can add one using the `headers` parameter for `mail()`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $emailbody = 'Name: '.$_POST['name']."\n"
  .'E-mail: '.$_POST['email']."\n"
  .'Phone: '.$_POST['phone']."\n"
  .'Address: '.$_POST['addr']."\n"
  .'City: '.$_POST['city']."\n"
  .'State: '.$_POST['state']."\n"
  .'Enquiry: '.$_POST['msg'];

  // Add extra headers here
  $headers = "From:address@examle.com"
  mail('myemail@email.com', 'Subject Line', $emailbody, $headers);

  header('location: index.html');
} else {
  header('location: about-us.html');
}
```

You should check any user-suplied input to ensure it doesn't try to subvert your mail function by adding headers of its own. Check for text like `To:`, `Cc:` or `Bcc:`.

Most ISPs will refuse to deliver email unless it comes from a domain registered with them. Sometimes the `from` address must exist on the server generating the mail.

Note that there are other reasons why mail might not be delivered: bad addressing and spam filters to name but two.

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried you above code with additional headers but still I the mail function is not working. It is the same case as before. I am not sure what modification still I can do in the code.

Comment: @user2554130 Apologies - there was a slight error in the additional header which I've now corrected. However, if you've tried the suggestion in one of the other answers you'll have covered this anyway. As I've already indicated, there are many reasons why mail won't be delivered this way, and you have no control over most of them. Start with the simplest case: can you deliver mail to an account held on the same server, and work from there. I'd also recommend that you try one of the libraries. See Spudley's comment for a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just changed **$emailbody** into **$message** and it is working fine now. I am not sure that using **$emailbody** instead of **$message** was the issue but it is working fine now.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

First check your hosting server is that providing  mail functionality  for this you just   write

```
 echo  phpinfo();
```

you need to check the mail function enable or not